# ASP send email form with attachment

Tags: asp-classic, email-attachments

I have an HTML form that sends an email on submit with this code. How do I go about sending an uploaded file as an attachment as well. I am new to asp and have looked at many examples but they are all very different and complex. Many thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="index.asp">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="file" name="myFile1" id="myFile1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ASP

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.AddAttachment "c:\mydocuments\test.txt"
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

So I got the above code to send an attachment, but I still have no idea how to go about attaching an uploaded file from my form? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Classic ASP or ASP.NET? Your code sample is for Classic ASP.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a difference, the above code works so maybe that means Classic ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use SaveAs or the InputStream to get any content into the attachment.

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) to the MSDN documentation.

Here is a way to attach a file to a mail.

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(saveLocation, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think this is way over my head. I read that its best to upload the file to the server and then remove it after sending the email. Do you know how this can be done with the provided code?